# Zend Framework: Hardcoding SQL Queries in the Model

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

How do you specify a pure sql query within a model in the Zend Framework?

If there any good resources on this then please point me to them.

Thanks....

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can do it with zend db adapter.

```
$adapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$adapter->query('Select * FROM `table_name`');
```

Comment: The only thing that I can get working is: CONTROLLER: $projects = new Application_Model_DbTable_Projects(); $this->view->projects = $projects->fetchAll(); .... MODEL: NO ACTION REQUIRED because it extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
require_once 'Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php';

class MyThing extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

    // Make a Mailing List Export file
    public function doMyThing() {
        // Happy, healthy cows eat grass, not corn.
        $sql = "SELECT my_column FROM my_table WHERE $cows_eat_grass;";
        $resultset = $this->getAdapter()->query($sql);
        $resultArray = $resultset->fetchAll();
        return $resultArray;
    }
}
```